# How to make a text appear from 0 to 100% (fold out effect) in KonvaJs

Tags: konvajs

In KonvaJS how to make a text appear from 0 to 100% (fold out effect)

i want to create same effect as in below video, but with text
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HO6mco2MGH0

i tried giving width 0 to the node and then increased the width to 100% in the tween. But it is not giving me the desired effect. Text is appear character by character.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

For that case, you can use [group clipping](https://konvajs.github.io/docs/clipping/Clipping_Regions.html).

```
const group = new Konva.Group({
  clipX: 100,
  clipY: 0,
  clipWidth: 100,
  clipHeight: 100
});
layer.add(group);

const circle = new Konva.Circle({
  x: 0,
  y: 50,
  radius: 50,
  fill: 'green'
});
group.add(circle);

circle.to({
  x: 150,
  duration: 1
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/miketotuvo/1/edit?html,js,output